# Refreshing data within a v-for loop without hard refresh once changes occur?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that displays a table containing data from a DB. my issue is once new data is submitted to this table, the component won't update without a hard refresh. is there a way to to force this component to re-render?

List Displayed

```
<p v-for="item in items" v-bind:class="{ active: item.active }">{{ item.text }}</p>
```

This component submits and posts data to DB then returns user to list component above. Changes don't reflect until hard refresh.

```
<form action="#"  @submit.prevent="postOptimization">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Save New Optimization</button>
// some data here to submit to DB
</form>
```

Original Render of list : https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Sqd.jpg

After submitting new data to list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI86l.jpg

List after changes but not displaying: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1K73.jpg

After hard refresh(displaying correctly): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNAyq.jpg

Comment: Please, provide more code.

Comment: You might want to fire an event (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) in the postOptimization method, and listen to it in the component.

Comment: How does the component get the data to begin with?

Comment: Add unique keys to your v-for loop: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: @RoyJ the data is pulled from the database initially. 

this.$http.get('/posts').then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.body;
    }),

then the list takes that information and displays it with the v-for loop.

Comment: Call that again once the data is saved.

Comment: @BillCriswell this worked. I'm trying to understand why though. is the change of the array storing the data not enough to trigger the change but a call to the server is?

Comment: You didn't show that part of your code so I didn't know that was a possibility. It should update the view for your if you're splicing the array.